# How do I run an executable in a different directory in C?

Tags: c, executable

I want to run an executable found in ../folder1/folder2 while inside of a C script.  Right now I'm trying to do:

```
char command[50];
strcpy(command, "cd ../folder1/folder2");
system(command);
memset(command,0,sizeof(command));
strcpy(command, "./executable_name");
system(command);
```

but it's not working.  Should I be using chdir(), or is there another way to do this?  Is it even possible?

Comment: Worketh not `strcpy(command, "../folder1/folder2/executable_name"); system(command);`?

Comment: Maybe you haven't access to certain folders

Comment: C isn't a scripted language; it sounds very peculiar to say "inside a C script".

Comment: Besides, `system()` spawns a subshell to execute your commands, so your `cd` would only apply within that subshell, which exits before a new one is created for your second command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because when you execute:

```
system("cd ../folder1/folder2");
```

it does not have an effect on the current directory of the executable. Hence, when you execute:

```
system("./executable_name");
```

it doesn't find it.

You can solve it using any of the following methods:

1. Change the command given to `system`:

   ```
   system("../folder1/folder2/executable_name");
   ```
2. Change the command given to `system`:

   This is going to work if your default shell is `bash`, and many of the UNIX shells.

   ```
   system("cd ../folder1/folder2; ./executable_name");
   ```
3. Create a shell script that has:

   ```
   #/bin/bash
   cd  ../folder1/folder2
   ./executable_name
   ```

   and then run the shell script from C using `system`

   ```
   system("myscript.sh");
   ```
4. Add a line to `chdir` in C before you call `system`:

   ```
   chdir("../folder1/folder2");
   system("./executable_name");
   ```

**Update, Thanks due to @Jongware**

All of the above assume that your program is executed in a directory from where `../folder1/folder2` is a valid path. If your program is executed from a different directory and you want to account for that scenario, you have to parse `argv[0]` and adjust the way you handle the calls to execute `executable_name`.

Comment: I got it working with chdir.  Thanks for explaining how system actually works.

Comment: .. but note that this still depends on your executable *starting in its own folder*. It is possible to start an executable in another folder, and then your (relative!) path will not be found wither.

Comment: @Jongware, good point. Do you mind if I add that to the answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahead. (Is parsing `argv[0]` a reliable solution? It might have been discussed on SO before.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is normally:

```
system("../folder1/folder2/executable_name");
```

Failing that, you have to either do the `cd` via `chdir()` in your program, or arrange to do the `cd` and execute the command in a single shell (single call to `system()`), as in:

```
system("cd ../folder1/folder2; ./executable_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that system, does a fork, executes the cd in a sub-process, which ends and does not effect the working directory of the program process.  Shells, need to make cd & dirs builtins for them to have an effect.

Rather than use a shell command, you can use `getwd` and `chdir` to change directory then system with `"."` as you tried, add a `"cd ../folder1/folder2; ./executable_name"`, use `fork` and change directory and run the command in the child with `exec` yourself, or alternatively just run the program using the relative path "../folder1/folder2/executable_name".

```
#include <unistd.h>

int chdir(const char *path);
char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute a script that changes the directory then runs the application.

Comment: (That's not true)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply execute a program using a relative or absolute path. If you actually want to execute it in another working directory, read on.

Currently your program does not change its working directory before executing the child program.

Simply explained, `system` starts a new program which changes its working directory and then exits, so *your program is not affected*.

What you tried works in actual scripts because the interpreter does not spawn a new shell for each command you give it, but executes them itself.

Use `chdir()` or some other API for changing the directory *of the currently executing program*.